Who said "When you see 666 on the kid's head, you know there's going to be trouble"
I've been googling for two weeks and my head is just about to explode. I know I've heard this reference to the Omen trilogy somewhere. Someone says something like "When you see 666 on the kid's head, you know there's going to be trouble". Instead of "head" it might have been "skull" and instead of "there's going to be trouble" it might be another foreboding statement of similar nature.
I've been combing the subtitles of Friends in case it's Chandler. And I've got the feeling it might be Nicolas Cage who says it. But I just can't find it and there are veins popping in my head... can you recognize the quote?

@Richard, I think it was said either humorously or sarcastically. And I think it might have been something like 10 years ago. I don't remember whether it was in reference to a newborn or not

There was definately a similar quote in 'Only Fools and Horses'
In the episode 'Three Men, a Woman and a Baby' Del and Raquel's baby is born and is called 'Damien' hence the '666' quote. There's definately some homage to the omen in the episode (and in further episodes).
Here's a link to the 666 bit: Damien Trotter.

Damien was born under a full moon and during the birth, Rodney even went as so far as to ask Del if the baby had been born with the numbers '666' branded on its forehead

